# Geofence enter/exit notification

Tags: android

I am using Geo-fence API. It is work but some times it gives notification and some time it gives notification to late. Also timing of notification is wrong.Please Help as soon as possible.

```
<receiver android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.GeofenceReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For handling transition

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            handleError(intent);
        } else {
            handleEnterExit(intent);
        }
    }

    private void handleError(Intent intent){
        // Get the error code
        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);

        // Get the error message
        String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
                context, errorCode);

        // Log the error
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_error_detail,
                        errorMessage));

        // Set the action and error message for the broadcast intent
        broadcastIntent
                .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);

        // Broadcast the error *locally* to other components in this app
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                broadcastIntent);
    }


        private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {
            // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
            int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

            // Test that a valid transition was reported
            if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

                // Post a notification
                List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient
                        .getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
                String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
                String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER,
                        geofenceIds);
                String transitionType = GeofenceUtils
                        .getTransitionString(transition);

                for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size(); index++) {
                    Geofence geofence = geofences.get(index);
                    ...do something with the geofence entry or exit. I'm saving them to a local sqlite db

                }
                // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
                broadcastIntent
                        .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                        .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                        .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_ID, geofenceIds)
                        .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_TYPE,
                                transitionType);

                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext())
                        .sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

                // Log the transition type and a message
                Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, transitionType + ": " + ids);
                Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                        context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

                // In debug mode, log the result
                Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, "transition");

                // An invalid transition was reported
            } else {
                // Always log as an error
                Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                        context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                                transition));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is
         * detected. If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the main
         * Activity.
         * 
         * @param transitionType
         *            The type of transition that occurred.
         * 
         */
        private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String locationName) {

            // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            // Construct a task stack
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

            // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

            // Push the content Intent onto the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

            // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
            PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions
            // >= 4
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context);

            // Set the notification contents
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(transitionType + ": " + locationName)
                    .setContentText(
                            context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                    .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

            // Get an instance of the Notification manager
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Issue the notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please extend your question with a specific example and some code or configuration.

Comment: I am using geofence APi and also declare in manifest broadcast receiver for handling transition.it gives notification but some times it gives wrong timing and some time some notification come late.

Comment: please help As soon as possible

Comment: Please define "gives notification to _late_" and "_timing_ of notification is _wrong_".

Comment: My device have two region of geo-fence and both  region give notification of enter/exit but timing of  notification is wrong.